# Access documents from docset

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

**Here's the background:**

There is a docset that contains documents. These documents have unique securities.
When I change a certain property of the docset, in the event handler I want the documents to update their security accordingly. (Most likely by either kicking off another event handler that changes the document security, or directly calling a function that updates the security.)

**Question**: Security aside, is it possible, and if so how, to access documents within a docset? i.e. from the docset as SPItemEventProperties.

**Example**:
I would expect it to look something like...

```
public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
  //... other stuff
  string oldDiv = Convert.ToString(properties.BeforeProperties["Division"]);
  string newDiv = Convert.ToString(properties.AfterProperties["Division"]);
  if (oldDiv != newDiv)
  {
    try
      {
        // update each document (that has security "My Division Team")
        foreach (documentx in properties.listitem.????) {
          if (documentx.securitylevel == "my division team") {
            updatesecurity(documentx); // this is my own custom function
}}}
```

Please correct me if the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: A docset is simply a folder with metadata. Try to search within the folder named like your docset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. As Steve B points out above it requires treating the docset as a folder. The magic line of code in this case is:

```
SPFileCollection docsinproject = properties.ListItem.Folder.Files;
foreach (SPFile doc in docsinproj) { .... }
```